# Im getting an error in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Im now getting this error ....Warning   1   Could not copy "obj\x86\Debug\HANGMAN-SHAPES V100.exe" to "bin\Debug\HANGMAN-SHAPES V100.exe". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\HANGMAN-SHAPES V100.exe' because it is being used by another process. HANGMAN-SHAPES V100

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory; the file is in use - maybe you have a debugging session still running? In any case you can terminate the process from the processes tab in the task manager.